# How to identify the db user in mongodb changestream event?

Tags: mongodb, changestream

Is there any way to identify the DB User in the MongoDB changestream event?

Suppose if two users modify the same document, I am looking for a way to distinguish between these two change events based on the user.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: its not possible, there are dedicated auditing tools in MongoDB.

One way you could do it though is to add user context to each change introduced by your back-end server side application, then such change would be part of every change event in the change stream. You could use this information for all sorts of things. However this way you could not identity users behind changes executed directly in the DB.

Another option is to check MongoDB logs, by default they only log slow operations - meaning all operations, which take more than 100ms to execute. You could change verbosity to extend logging (however with the downside of log storage size). In case you use logs - you see specific user's opening specific connections, and then these connections being used to execute queries/commands.